# How can I get back ASP.NET Core verbose request logging in 3.x

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging

If you create a new web application project in .NET Core 2.1 and 3.1, there is a difference in verbosity when starting them

.NET Core 2.1 looks like this
[image: Request Logging in .NET Core 2.1]

.NET Core 3.1 looks like this
[image: Request Logging in .NET Core 3.1]

How can I get these additional messages in 3.1?

I noted that instead of `WebHost`, 3.1 uses `Host` in Program.cs. But even if I change it back it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to get requests and route matching related **Information** level logs in `Console` output, you can try to add following setting in the `Logging` section of appsettings.json file.

```
"Console": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Microsoft": "Information"
  }
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know you could configure different logging providers like this. I always thouhg it's global. And my global "Default" is on "Trace". I don't really get why the default is not enough and you'd have to configure it this specific...